# Failing to build R Pi Pico "Hello World" program

Tags: c++, python-3.x, visual-studio, embedded, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm attempting to get started with the R Pi Pico. I'm unable to build the introductory "Hello World" program using the command line tools. The nmake command fails, reporting that the C compiler cl.exe is not able to compile a simple test program.

I'm following section 9.2.3 of [Getting Starting with Pico](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/pico/getting-started-with-pico.pdf).

My installation steps are outlined in the [readme at my github repo](https://github.com/krisradio/PiPico#readme). Of note: I'm using VS2022 and Python 3.10, instead of VS2019 and Python 3.9. Those *were* the modern versions when the Pico guide was written, but they're outdated now.

Here is the complete output of my (failed) build attempt:

```
C:\Users\7hesa\Documents\WWU\EECE\RPiPico\Projects\pico-examples\build>cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" ..
Using PICO_SDK_PATH from environment ('C:\Users\7hesa\Documents\WWU\EECE\RPiPico\Toolchain\pico-sdk')
PICO_SDK_PATH is C:/Users/7hesa/Documents/WWU/EECE/RPiPico/Toolchain/pico-sdk
Defaulting PICO_PLATFORM to rp2040 since not specified.
Defaulting PICO platform compiler to pico_arm_gcc since not specified.
-- Defaulting build type to 'Release' since not specified.
PICO compiler is pico_arm_gcc
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.3.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.3.1
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain/10 2021.10/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe
Defaulting PICO target board to pico since not specified.
Using board configuration from C:/Users/7hesa/Documents/WWU/EECE/RPiPico/Toolchain/pico-sdk/src/boards/include/boards/pico.h
-- Found Python3: C:/Users/7hesa/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe (found version "3.10.1") found components: Interpreter
TinyUSB available at C:/Users/7hesa/Documents/WWU/EECE/RPiPico/Toolchain/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/portable/raspberrypi/rp2040; enabling build support for USB.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/7hesa/Documents/WWU/EECE/RPiPico/Projects/pico-examples/build

C:\Users\7hesa\Documents\WWU\EECE\RPiPico\Projects\pico-examples\build>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.30.30706.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Scanning dependencies of target bs2_default
[  0%] Building ASM object pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/CMakeFiles/bs2_default.dir/compile_time_choice.S.obj
[  0%] Linking ASM executable bs2_default.elf
[  0%] Built target bs2_default
[  0%] Generating bs2_default.bin
[  0%] Generating bs2_default_padded_checksummed.S
[  0%] Built target bs2_default_padded_checksummed_asm
[  0%] Creating directories for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[  0%] No download step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[  0%] No update step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[  0%] No patch step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[  0%] Performing configure step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.30.30706.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.30.30706.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.30.30705/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.30.30705/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.30.30705/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/7hesa/Documents/WWU/EECE/RPiPico/Projects/pico-examples/build/elf2uf2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):nmake -f Makefile /nologo cmTC_d8505\fast &&   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"  -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_d8505.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_d8505.dir\build
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_d8505.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
        "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_cl_compile_depends --dep-file=CMakeFiles\cmTC_d8505.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj.d --working-dir=C:\Users\7hesa\Documents\WWU\EECE\RPiPico\Projects\pico-examples\build\elf2uf2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp --filter-prefix="Note: including file: " -- C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\2022\PROFES~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1430~1.307\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe @C:\Users\7hesa\AppData\Local\Temp\nm70F7.tmp
    testCCompiler.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_d8505.exe
        "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_d8505.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests -- C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\2022\PROFES~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1430~1.307\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_d8505.dir\objects1.rsp @C:\Users\7hesa\AppData\Local\Temp\nm7156.tmp
    RC Pass 1: command "rc /fo CMakeFiles\cmTC_d8505.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_d8505.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
    The system cannot find the file specifiedNMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"' : return code '0xffffffff'
    Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
    Stop.





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/7hesa/Documents/WWU/EECE/RPiPico/Projects/pico-examples/build/elf2uf2/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/7hesa/Documents/WWU/EECE/RPiPico/Projects/pico-examples/build/elf2uf2/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'echo' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
C:\Users\7hesa\Documents\WWU\EECE\RPiPico\Projects\pico-examples\build>cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" ..
Using PICO_SDK_PATH from environment ('C:\Users\7hesa\Documents\WWU\EECE\RPiPico\Toolchain\pico-sdk')
PICO_SDK_PATH is C:/Users/7hesa/Documents/WWU/EECE/RPiPico/Toolchain/pico-sdk
Defaulting PICO_PLATFORM to rp2040 since not specified.
Defaulting PICO platform compiler to pico_arm_gcc since not specified.
-- Defaulting build type to 'Release' since not specified.
PICO compiler is pico_arm_gcc
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.3.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.3.1
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain/10 2021.10/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe
Defaulting PICO target board to pico since not specified.
Using board configuration from C:/Users/7hesa/Documents/WWU/EECE/RPiPico/Toolchain/pico-sdk/src/boards/include/boards/pico.h
-- Found Python3: C:/Users/7hesa/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe (found version "3.10.1") found components: Interpreter
TinyUSB available at C:/Users/7hesa/Documents/WWU/EECE/RPiPico/Toolchain/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/portable/raspberrypi/rp2040; enabling build support for USB.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/7hesa/Documents/WWU/EECE/RPiPico/Projects/pico-examples/build

C:\Users\7hesa\Documents\WWU\EECE\RPiPico\Projects\pico-examples\build>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.30.30706.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Scanning dependencies of target bs2_default
[  0%] Building ASM object pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/CMakeFiles/bs2_default.dir/compile_time_choice.S.obj
[  0%] Linking ASM executable bs2_default.elf
[  0%] Built target bs2_default
[  0%] Generating bs2_default.bin
[  0%] Generating bs2_default_padded_checksummed.S
[  0%] Built target bs2_default_padded_checksummed_asm
[  0%] Creating directories for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[  0%] No download step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[  0%] No update step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[  0%] No patch step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[  0%] Performing configure step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.30.30706.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.30.30706.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.30.30705/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.30.30705/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.30.30705/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/7hesa/Documents/WWU/EECE/RPiPico/Projects/pico-examples/build/elf2uf2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):nmake -f Makefile /nologo cmTC_d8505\fast &&   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"  -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_d8505.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_d8505.dir\build
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_d8505.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
        "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_cl_compile_depends --dep-file=CMakeFiles\cmTC_d8505.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj.d --working-dir=C:\Users\7hesa\Documents\WWU\EECE\RPiPico\Projects\pico-examples\build\elf2uf2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp --filter-prefix="Note: including file: " -- C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\2022\PROFES~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1430~1.307\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe @C:\Users\7hesa\AppData\Local\Temp\nm70F7.tmp
    testCCompiler.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_d8505.exe
        "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_d8505.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests -- C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\2022\PROFES~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1430~1.307\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_d8505.dir\objects1.rsp @C:\Users\7hesa\AppData\Local\Temp\nm7156.tmp
    RC Pass 1: command "rc /fo CMakeFiles\cmTC_d8505.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_d8505.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
    The system cannot find the file specifiedNMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"' : return code '0xffffffff'
    Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
    Stop.





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/7hesa/Documents/WWU/EECE/RPiPico/Projects/pico-examples/build/elf2uf2/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/7hesa/Documents/WWU/EECE/RPiPico/Projects/pico-examples/build/elf2uf2/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'echo' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Thank you, any help will be greatly appreciated.
I am going to attempt to build from VS Studio GUI now.
Cheers!

Comment: Questions about how to get a particular lib or tool chain up and running might be more suited for https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks @Lundin, I'll ask it there then. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The solution: I forgot to install the Windows 10 SDK. That was an important step in the "Getting Started" pdf that I somehow overlooked.

After this, it still wouldn't compile due to a known bug with nmake. I turned to Ninja instead, and it compiled on the first try! Woohoo!